# How to get value of a <input> by clicking another <input> in same <tr> different <td>

Tags: jquery

```
<tr class="item-row" id="itemsRow">
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="tInput" id="invoiceNo" readonly/> </td>
      <td><input class="tInput" id="clientId" readonly /> </td>
      <td><input class="tInput" id="issueDate"  readonly/></td>
      <td><inpu  class="tInput" id="netTotal" readonly /> </td>
      <td><input class="tInput" id="amountDue" readonly /> </td>
      <td><input class="tInput" id="status" readonly /> </td>
 </tr>
```

Im trying to get value of 'input id=invoiceNo' when I click to 'input id=status' using following code

```
var invno = $(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(2) input').val();
alert(invno);
```

It alerts 'undefined'

so how to solve this?

Comment: Using DOM traversal to locate an element that has an ID (which should be unique to the page) is slower, more complex to write, and slightly less obvious to anybody else reading the code. Just use an ID selector instead.

Comment: err, am I the only one who sees the problem having multiple ID's that are the same - one in each table row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` does only search in the `parent()` array.
So you have to search in your parent element:

```
var invno = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2) input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
var invo = $(this).parents('tr').find('#invoiceNo').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
   $(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(1)').find('input#invoiceNo').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an ID that **should** be unique to that page (if it isn't, you need to fix that), so just select the element directly using a standard ID selector (`$('#invoiceNo').val();`). There's no need to do DOM traversal.